# RHEL - shutdown a locked out system

Tags: linux, login, console

I have a RHEL system which is locked out. I don't have the password of the system. If am able to shut it down or properly restart it, I can edit the kernel to have single mode and then reset the password. But for that, I need to shut down the system without affecting any of the user processes.

Is there any way of doing it rather than the long press or killing of the power?

Comment: What do you mean "shut down the system without affecting any of the user processes"? Surely you are aware that all user processes are killed on shutdown, right?

Comment: yeah. I actually meant the system should not be killed abruptly.

Comment: Hmmm... if you don't have the password of the system, then you're definitely not allowed to hijack the root account. Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a system in the lab which is locked by an user. I need to shut down this system. One solution that comes to my mind is taking remote of the locked out machine from another machine as a root user. However, for that I do not remember the root password. Is there any way to specify like machine ID or something to reset the root password and then log in remotely to the locked out machine?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. If you want to reset the root password remotely, you need the old root password, period. IMO, the "correct" solution is to ask this user to unlock his/her machine for you.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. This user is out of the school and so I have to figure out some other way lol

Comment: @Ramesh - do you have sudo rights on this computer?

Comment: I think I might have sudo rights on this computer.

Comment: I can't tell if you have physical access or not. But if you do, CTRL+ALT+DEL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most modern systems, pressing the power button (without holding it down), will send a ACPI signal and will cause the OS to shut down normally.

Some servers come with remote management cards. An example is a Dell iDRAC or HP iLO. If your server has a remote management card (and you have the password to that) you should be able to perform a graceful shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to gain access to a system that you do not have root privileges on is to power cycle the system, typically by holding the power button in and counting to say 10. Once the system is shutdown, turn the power back on via the power button. 
As the system boots you'll get to the Grub menu.

Once in the Grub menu you can get into any system so long as you have console access and there isn't a password preventing you from gaining access to the Grub menu.

During the initial boot up of the system when the Grub menu shows up, if you enter the menu and edit (press <kbd>e</kbd> key) the kernel line, you can add one of the following things to make the kernel boot in single user mode.

- single
- init=/bin/sh
- 1

The line will look something like this:

```
 kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.15-27-386 root=/dev/mapper/Ubuntu-root ro init=/bin/bash
```

In Grub it should look similar to this:

[image: ss of grub]

Once you've made the changes boot the kernel (press key <kbd>b</kbd>).

This will give you temporary access to the system with a shell where you can use vi/vim to make whatever changes you need to your `/etc/passwd` file. Just type `reboot` when you're done.

Comment: The OP seems aware of this method. What they want is to avoid the power cycling or to at least achieve a graceful shut down.

Comment: @JosephR. - yeah he seemed somewhat familiar with this process, I was merely adding the actual steps to accomplish it on the offhanded chance that he wanted to go this route. But as you and others have mentioned in comments, without a remote management card or root it's not possible by any other means.

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is networked and you have an account, log in remotely. If you want to reboot, you'll need to have root access (through sudo, su or whatever).

If you have an account and you are present physically, switch to another virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.). You'll get a login prompt. Run `startx -- :1` if you want to have a graphical interface. If all you wanted to do is work on the machine, that's good enough, you can keep the other guy's session running.

If you have physical access, you may be able to initiate a reboot by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> (this can be enabled or disabled by the system administrator and I don't know whether RHEL has it enabled by default). You may need to switch to a text console first (see above). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is equivalent to running `reboot` as root.

If you really need to reboot that machine and you are physically present but have no account, you can use the [magic Sysrq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). This is almost never disabled. Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then press <kbd>SysRq</kbd> and then <kbd>S</kbd>, and finally release <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Repeat with the letters <kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd>. <kbd>S</kbd> flushes the disk buffers, <kbd>U</kbd> forcibly unmounts filesystems (it marks them as clean for fsck purposes, but applications get no opportunity to save their files), and <kbd>B</kbd> triggers a hard reboot.