# RHEL - not able to write in /opt as root

Tags: linux, rhel

I am trying to copy a virtual box image inside **/opt** folder in *RHEL 5.6*. I am logged in as the *root* and I strangely see that I am not able to write anything into **/opt** folder. I checked the permissions from other machines in the lab and see that the permissions are set correctly. However, in the **/etc/fstab** file in all the remaining machines (where everything is correct and working fine), I see the below entry.

```
LABEL = /home1 /opt ext3 defaults 1 2
```

In the faulty machine where **/opt** directory is not writable, I see the **/etc/fstab** file entry as,

```
LABEL = /home /opt ext3 defaults 1 2
```

I am quite new to system administration and I believe it has to do something with the improper mounting of the file system as read only. I checked the **dmesg** for any errors but was not able to understand it. I think I have to remount the **/opt** with the proper settings. But I don't want to do anything in the lab to disturb the current setup. I just wanted to know if my understanding is correct and, is it the missing "**1**" in **/etc/fstab** file causing the **/opt** to be read only?

**EDIT:**

After I run the mount command,

The output from the faulty machine,

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda5 on /opt type ext3 (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
XXXserver.XXX.XXX:/opt/vbox_image on /opt/vbox_image type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.1.10)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
```

The output from the correct machine

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda5 on /opt type ext3 (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
ascentserver.uta.edu:/opt/vbox_image on /opt/vbox_image type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.1.10)
**none on /proc/fs/vmblock/mountPoint type vmblock (rw)**
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
```

**EDIT 2:**

If I run the command, `for i in $( cat /proc/partitions | awk '{ print $4 }' ) ; do e2label /dev/$i ; done`, I get the below output. I am not able to debug this output.

```
e2label: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/name
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
e2label: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
/boot1
/1
e2label: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda3
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
e2label: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda4
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
/home
```

**EDIT 3:**

The `ls-l` command on /opt directory shows I have rwx permission on all the files inside it. However, I tried creating a simple text file and it was not allowing me to create the file.

Comment: The `1` looks more like a typo. However `/etc/fstab` is not what you should consult, since it is a list of how file systems are intended to be mounted. What you need here is a list of *actual* mounts - either the output of `mount` or `/proc/mounts` will give you the actual state of the system. And there you may see the mounted filesystem to be read only. Also check you don't have any hardening in place that could prevent even root from writing into `/opt`.

Comment: It could be that your mounting via filesystem label (home1 being the label of the disk, device, or partition.)  Your first step would be to see what the filesystem labels are for a 'good' host and your faulty host.  On each, what is the output of #  for i in $( cat /proc/partitions | awk '{ print $4 }' ) ; do e2label /dev/$i ; done

Comment: Are we talking about the same `/opt` for all machines (i.e. a network share)? If not, then it may be that the pathological host has an unclean filesystem on `/opt`. Especially if you have [power cycled it as you were suggesting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93085/rhel-shutdown-a-locked-out-system). The solution may be to unmount it and `fsck` it. This would definitely disrupt users of this host, though, so you may want to plan some downtime for it if you decide to go this way.

Comment: @peterph, I ran the mount command and updated the output of mount command from the faulty machine as well as the correctly working machine. In the correctly working machine, there is one extra entry as, none on /proc/fs/vmblock/mountPoint type vmblock (rw). Otherwise, the output is the same in both the machines.

Comment: @JosephR, this is a different machine in the lab. It has all the settings exactly as it is for the remaining machines in the network. I was able to use the virtual box image in all of the machines in the network. However, in this machine alone I am getting this weird read only error. I also tried the mount command, but I am not able to debug any useful info from it.

Comment: @stephan, I ran the command that you provided. I have updated the question with the output for your command in the EDIT 2 section. I am not sure on how to debug using the output that I got.

Comment: @Ramesh can you provide the output of `lsattr -d /opt`? If you have a `i` present (`----i----------`) then do `chattr -i /opt` and it should then work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the **fsck** command as suggested in the chat window. After unmounting the volume and running the fsck command, I got an error as "**bad or duplicate blocks foun**d" and fsck command seemed to fix that issue.

After this step, I checked the access to write under **/opt** folder and it was also fine. I thought of installing the windows from a .ova file and deleted the older one (This *windows7.ova* was present under /opt folder and it was one of the files that was giving the duplicate or bad block error). I deleted that image and everything went for a toss. The system suddenly started giving read-only error and when I restarted it was not giving me anything.

I figured may be reinstalling RHEL in the system with new partitions might help and did that. However, I encountered an error at the end saying "**Installation failed**". But the system was loading fine and I was able to login as the root.

I installed the virtualbox and tried to install Windows 7 again inside the VirtualBox. Again, I got the error saying "**The file is corrupted**". This time when I googled the error, most of the pages suggested it might be a hard drive issue. So, I heavily suspect this error was caused due to some bad sectors in the hard drive.

Please correct me if am wrong. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Run the command `showmount -e XXXserver.XXX.XXX` where this is the server serving this NFS mount: `/opt/vbox_image`.

What's most likely happening is that the server giving you access to this NFS share has the `root_squash` bit turned on for this NFS exported share. This disallows the root user from remote systems that mount this shared mount, from having the ability to access it.

*excerpt from [18.7. The /etc/exports Configuration File](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-server-config-exports.html)*

> **root_squash** — Prevents root users connected remotely from having root
>   privileges and assigns them the user ID for the user nfsnobody. This
>   effectively "squashes" the power of the remote root user to the lowest
>   local user, preventing unauthorized alteration of files on the remote
>   server. Alternatively, the no_root_squash option turns off root
>   squashing. To squash every remote user, including root, use the
>   all_squash option. To specify the user and group IDs to use with
>   remote users from a particular host, use the anonuid and anongid
>   options, respectively. In this case, a special user account can be
>   created for remote NFS users to share and specify
>   (anonuid=,anongid=), where  is the
>   user ID number and  is the group ID number.

Comment: `/opt` itself (the one where the OP is facing problems) seems to be a local mount.

Comment: @JosephR. - are you sure? Look at this line:
`XXXserver.XXX.XXX:/opt/vbox_image on /opt/vbox_image`

Comment: Yeah and ls -l command on /opt gives me rwx access. But I was not able to create a text file inside /opt folder and I also checked if I have enough space on my disk using df -h command.

Comment: @Ramesh - do a `df /opt` that will tell you where it's coming from.

Comment: As I said the permissions don't mean anything if this is a mount. Permissions is one aspect of determining if you have access to a directory, they aren't the only thing. Things like root_squash and SELinux can override this and make it look like you should have access but do not.

Comment: @slm, it shows me the file system as /dev/sda5 and mounted on as /opt. It also shows me use% as 13%.

Comment: @Ramesh - Where did you get the output for the mount command above then?

Comment: @Ramesh - what does `df /opt/vbox_image` show? That's the mount point then, I would suspect.

Comment: `df \opt\vbox_image` gives me the output as XXXserver.xxx.xxx: /opt/vbox_image. For the `mount` command, I ran the command in the faulty machine and I got the output from the faulty machine only.

Comment: @Ramesh - yes so I was correct, it's a mount point. You need to see how it is exported to you. `showmount -e XXXserver.xxx.xxx`

Comment: But, can `root_squash` be the reason for not able to create a text file inside the `/opt/` directory?

Comment: I ran the `showmount -e XXXserver.xxx.xxx` command. I do see the `/home/users` and `/opt/vbox_image` for all the clients (This includes my affected machine as well).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10865/discussion-between-ramesh-and-slm)